# Rspec should_receive has me stumped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I need to test whether an instance method gets called on a particular instance as a result of calling a class method. Something like:

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.roll_trained
    Dog.all.each { |d| d.rollover if d.trained? }
  end

  def rollover
    # rollover and stuff
  end
  def trained?
    self.trained == true
  end
end
```

I've written a test like:

```
describe 'Dog.roll_trained' do
  it 'rolls trained dogs' do
    dog_1 = Dog.create(trained: true)
    dog_1.should_receive(:rollover)
    Dog.roll_trained
  end
end
```

I thought I had this right, but the test fails. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that dog_1 and the instances which are looped on the Dog.each is not the same instance.
This is because ActiveRecord generates a different instance for the same row (dog_1) in the database when you do Dog.each

I have written a blog post on this which you can read here: [ActiveRecord and In-Memory Object State](http://railsadventures.wordpress.com/2012/11/24/activerecord-and-in-memory-object-state/)

One solution would be to stub Dog.all - `Dog.stub(all: [dog_1])`

Another solution is to save the `trained` attribute to the database and then spec against the database: `dog_1.reload.trained.should be_true`